# on form submit send email+open pop up

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form which on submit should open a window and also send form data to email.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form" onsubmit="paymentfunc();return false;">
```

Submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Purchase" class="btn" id="submit" name="submit">
```

I have all the php code to send form data to email is written in the same file as that of form html.
Problem is that any one of the two actions are happening. How to make both happen?

Comment: What is the extension of your Form file?

Comment: do ajax request from your jquery to submit form and on success open your popup

Comment: Use [ajaxSubmit](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). This will provide you form action handlers like `beforeSubmit`, `success`, `error`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `return false;` in `onsubmit`
or change it to `return true;`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you use "return false;" this cancels the submit event. Therefore only the paymentfunc(); will be executed. If you remove the return false; your form will probably work.

Comment: There is no PHP code involved. It is just in the html user1829305 posted

Comment: you send form values to email means? how to send form values email what is that code? what is your email code?